# How to disable Workspace animation on OS X El-capitan

Tags: macos

I hate the animations when you switch workspaces (CMD + <-) & (CMD + ->)
Is there a way to completely disable those or speed it up a little?

Thanks

Comment: You should ask this on Apple.SE. Also, have you tried using the trackpad gesture? Or do you use a mouse? I've just tried it, and the trackpad gesture is technically faster than the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I use MacBook PRO and I have external displays... I use mouse and keyboard, so... trackpad is always to far away to reach it ;)

Comment: What mouse? [You can use Magic Mouse to switch to another space](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204100)

Comment: Just some small Logitech mouse, I don't use Apple Mouse, I've spend years on linux and don't want to change my habits ;)

Answer (score 1):

TotalSpaces2 addresses the problem. I've used it right up to Mavericks for years but you need to disable SIP on El Capitan. Probably not an issue if you know what you are doing. See http://totalspaces.binaryage.com/elcapitan

Comment: You should probably mention that it's a big security risk to adjust the SIP.

Comment: Indeed. However, TotalSpaces has now released an update where this is no longer required. See http://totalspaces.binaryage.com/elcapitan-with-sip

Comment: I don't like it - I'd like to be able to switch to the exact app with keyboard, or specific desktop at least. TS2 doesn't support that